# Javascript : page loses focus after opening mail client

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, mailer

Help!

I have an iPad app which runs html5 pages... one of the pages requires an email to be sent which opens the Mail program using this code

```
    var link = 'mailto:' + toEmailAdd +'?subject=PDFs&body='+htmlString
    window.open(link, 'Mailer');
```

After I send the email and go back to the program the page has lost focus and has the loading circle running in front of it.

Any help on how to make sure the page doesn't lose focus would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out...

```
$('#addBtn').bind( "click", function() {
  var link = 'mailto:' + toEmailAdd +'?subject=PDFs&body='+htmlString
  window.open(link, 'Mailer');  
  setTimeout(ResetPage, 1);
});

function ResetPage(){ 
    document.location = ""; 
};
```